# Find all instances and hide rows

Tags: excel, vba

I have a column which can either take values of `x` or `0`:

```
x
x
0
0
x
0
```

I am looking for a fast macro which will find all `x` values and hide these rows. I can do this by using `For each cell .. next` but I am thinking there must be a faster way using an array or something.

Comment: Seems like a candidate for Excel's built-in auto-filter capability.  Shouldn't require a macro at all.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `SpecialCells()` function to find text values. Then, hide just those rows.

Assuming you want to check column `A`, this should do the trick:

```
Range("A:A").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants, xlTextValues).EntireRow.Hidden = True
```

**Edit**: Per @Jeeped's comment below

If you're using formulas and you have your formula return `0` instead of `"0"`, then this should work:

```
Range("A:A").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeFormulas, xlTextValues).EntireRow.Hidden = True
```

Comment: the results "x" and "0" are created using a formula. will still this work? if not, maybe i can change the "0" to just blank..?

Comment: If the zeroes are returned as `0` and not `"0"` then this will work by changing `xlCellTypeConstants` to `xlCellTypeFormulas`. See [Range.SpecialCells method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff196157.aspx).

Comment: fwiw, F5, Special, Formulas, Text is a quick way to test this method without writing a line of code.

Answer (score 0):

The following assumes a column header label in A1.

```
with activesheet
    if .autofiltermode then .autofiltermode = false
    with .range(.cells(1,1), .cells(rows.count, 1).end(xlup))
        .autofilter field:=1, criteria1:="x", VisibleDropDown:=False
    end with
end with
```

This is just an [AutoFilter Method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa221844%28v=office.11%29.aspx) with the little arrow hidden. You can unhide the rows with conventional unhide commands or Data ► Sort & Filter ► Clear or simply turning off the AutoFilter.